# Question about the formula for calculating the chi-square

Tags: chi-squared-test

So, I know that the chi-square distribution $\chi^2$ is derived from $Z^2$, where $Z=\frac{(X-\mu)}{\sigma}$ and if there is more than one degree of freedom it is derived from a sum of the squares of k Z's. https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/16/16.5 is the best site I've seen for the derivation. But I've seen that when calculating the $\chi^2$ value to compare if it is lower than our critical value for example 3.84 for a significance level $\alpha=0.05$ they use $\chi^2=\sum_i\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$, where $O_i$ is the observed count of category i and $E_i$ is the expected count of category i.

Now my question where did our standard deviation $\sigma$ go an are $\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{(O-E)^2}{E}$ and aren't logically aren't $X=O;E=\mu$?

Comment: If you assume the counts have a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) then their variances would be equal to their means

Comment: On the other hand if you condition on the total (the sum of X's) then the X's will be multinomial; they're no longer independent. Under certain conditions. In standardized form they're *approximately* jointly normal under certain conditions but they lie in a $k-1$ dimensional subspace.